# Lexical field of a word

Tags: nouns

To find words belonging to a lexical field do I need to only look at hyponyms, hypernyms, antonyms and meronyms of that word only ?

For example what would be the words that belong to the lexical field of the city of Strasbourg in France ?

In other words what is the best way to find those and not get it wrong ?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean 'semantic field' (which would allow collocates, and associates such as Rhine, Cathédrale Notre-Dame? _When I think of Strasbourg, I think of ..._) 'Lexical field' seems far narrower: 'A lexeme is often thought of as a word in its most basic form. A lexical field is then the range of words which could apply in a given position of a sentence, each with a slightly different connotation.' [[HomeworkHelp](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-difference-between-semantic-field-lexical-300355)]

Comment: YOu might get more appropriate answers over at [linguistics.se]. There's nothing particular to English in this question; these are all universal linguistic concepts.

Comment: Besides being off topic here (as the process you’re looking for) would be applicable to many languages, you need to first clearly define what you mean by “lexical field”.

Comment: But you can probly find what you need by looking at [Labov's cup experiment.](https://improbable.com/2017/02/23/is-it-a-mug-or-cup-recent-progress-in-fuzziness-studies/)

Answer (score 1):

> Lexical fields
>
> Based on research in historical semantics, Jost Trier (1931) introduced the term lexical field (or semantic field) that he defined as a set of semantically related words whose meanings delimit each other. Thus, the meaning of a word can only be fully determined in terms of contrasts in which it stands with other words in the field. From a diachronic perspective, this means that any change in the meaning of one word affects the meaning of other words to which it is related. According to Trier, the members of a field cover a whole conceptual or objective domain without any gaps or overlaps, i.e. the boundaries of a lexical field can be clearly delimited. Criticism of this conception of lexical fields brought about differentiations and modifications of lexical field theory and led in the development of componential analysis.
>
> [Ello](http://www.ello.uos.de/field.php/Semantics/SemanticsLexicalfields)

From such notions I take the question to relate to the delineation of sets of related words. Let us see how far we can get. I will not burden my readers with tedious examples of the various -nym terms.

There are at least three relevant themes to examine and I do so only briefly in the hope that others may add and criticize constructively:

**The Word, Hypernyms and Hyponyms**

In the set of all words is the word we are interested in. I refer to it as **Word**.
Hyponyms are a subset of the meanings of **Word**.
**Word** is a subset of the words in its hypernyms.
At their simplest, these relations are easily represented in a Venn diagram of the sets:

[image]

**Antonyms and Synonyms**

It is useful to introduce the concept of mapping.

Ideally, a synonym means exactly the same as **Word**; there is a perfect mapping of one to the other. Antonym means the exact opposite as **Word**; there is a perfect mapping from {not Word} to the antonym.

This ideal is rarely realised in language, where we must often recognize that our words and sets are not as clearly defined as this ideal or as in the previous paragraph. Our sets are fuzzy, with ill-defined boundaries.

No word is common to the sets of antonyms and synonyms but there are shades of meaning on the set boundaries where a word is not exactly synonymous or antonymous with **Word**. The mappings are imperfect.

[image]

**Meromyns**

Meronyms merit a little extra analysis. The meronyms may be seen as the mapping of the meaning of **Word** onto one or more other words, the set of meronyms. To find meronyms we have to find these mappings, subtle, complicated, obscure as they might be.

[image]

**Summary**

The first question asks us how words relating to **Word** may be found from the set of all words. It asks if there are other sets above the relevant sets of  hypo-, hyper-, syno-, anto-, and meronyms. On first sight, and consistent with my analysis above, these might be assumed to cover all relevant sets; indeed, as I write I cannot think of another useful set to include.

I do not deal with the second exemplary question about Strasbourg.

As to the third question, I argue from the set approach that the search for any of the words in these sets - perhaps especially the meronyms, antonyms and synonyms - is beset with difficulties of meanings and definitions that may only be overcome in a case-by-case manner. Words do not come with definitive tags that allow them to be sorted or classified uniquely into the sorts of sets, fuzzy sets or mapped sets that I have outlined. There is therefore no mechanistic or algorithmic way to find words related to Word from the set of all words.

Comment: Additional problems are polysemy-with-hypernymy (a 'word' is its own hypernym) and the fact that (reasonably defined, ie non-exact) synonymy is non-transitive (in the sense of relations), thus _A is a synonym of B_ and _B is a synonym of C_ does not guarantee that _A is a synonym of C_.